# How to do a DirectorySearch of a specific directory in WIX

Tags: wix

I am trying to determine if a directory is installed to see if I should install a third party client or not.

```
<util:DirectorySearch Path="C:\Program Files (x86)\CenterSpace\NMath 5.0 and NMath Stats 3.3"
                      Variable="NmathInstalled"/>
```

When I do this candle.exe errors out and tells me that the directory "is not a valid relative long name because it contains illegal characters."  and eludes to the fact that ':' is illegal.  How can I search for a directory in c:\ without the ':'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your particular case, use the [Burn Built-in Variable](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/bundle_built_in_variables.htm) `ProgramFilesFolder` to have the `C:\Program Files (x86)\` resolve to the correct location on the machine. That link to the documentaiton has lots of other folder options.

Comment: I figured it would be something relatively simple.  Apparently my google-foo was not up to finding the answer though.  Thanks for the help.